# How to make HTML input tag only accept numbers between 18-65

Tags: html

I'm creating a sign-up form and one of the tags require you to enter your age. You can only create an account if you're older than 18 years old. So I thought I could achieve this by adding "pattern='18-65'". But that isn't working out. Right now, you can choose any number, even negative numbers. What am I doing wrong?

```
<input class="required" type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age (e.g. 25)" data-type="number" pattern="18-65">
```

Comment: I don't think "pattern" is working for some reason. It doesn't turn red when I type it. It's just black text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `min` and `max` attributes.

```
<input type="number" name="age" min="18" max="65">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use min and max attribute to define the desired range.

```
<input class="required" type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age (e.g. 25)" min="18" max="65" />
```